# Is there any directives to change Angular material icon size?

Tags: angular-material

I am using angular material for icons,

```
<mat-icon>subdirectory_arrow_right</mat-icon>
```

default size of icon is defined by the framework as 24px, Is there any directive to resize it? like how we have in font awesome - lg/sm/md

Answer (score 2):

In v6.x you can use the `inline` property to have your icons match font size with their parent elements. Otherwise, there is no built-in MatIcon feature for specifying the icon size when using the default icon font set. You can easily add a style property e.g. `style="font-size: 16px;"` or you could defined your own class to do that. You might also want to set width and height since like font-size, those default to 24.

Comment: Yes, tried all possible ways.. ended up adding a customized class to resize . anyways, thank you for your response.